# How to pass parameters to MySQL script when running through cmd?

Tags: mysql, sql, cmd

I am trying to pass parameters to my sql script via cmd on Windows but it does not work nor do I get any errors though.

This will be running on a Windows environment and executed using cmd. I have the following code in my deploy.sql script:

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`users` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `active`)
    VALUES (1, @first_name, @last_name, @user_name, 1);
```

I want to pass 3 strings to my script but it does not work. If I hard code a the strings in the script then I can execute the script via cmd perfectly.

The command I am trying to run to pass the parameters and execute the script is:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p -e "set @first_name='John'; set @last_name='Smith'; set @user_name='john.smith';" < deploy.sql
```

My database is not updating nor do I get any errors. If I run the command with -v for a verbose output I get:

```
--------------
set @first_name='John'
--------------
--------------
set @last_name='Smith'
--------------
--------------
set @user_name='john.smith'
--------------
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by using `\. deploy.sql` inconjunction with `-e` instead of specifying my script file like `< deploy.sql`.

Here is the working code:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p -e "set @first_name='John'; set @last_name='Smith'; set @user_name='john.smith'; \. deploy.sql"
```